# How to override the semantic UI Form Input Color?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have been trying to override a semantic UI CSS property in a form input element. I want to change the background color in the input field to white. It keeps showing yellow. I just am testing out different colors and borders trying to get them to work. But nothing does. I have been trying to change it for hours now. Any suggestions?

I have tried the following CSS (and many other things) and none of it works. I am expecting for the background color of the semantic UI form input selector to change because I am trying to over ride it with CSS.

CSS

```
input {
  background-color: blue !important;
} 

ui.input {

  background-color: blue !important;

}
#root > div > div > div.form-container > div > div > form{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
#root > div > div > div.form-container > div > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > div{
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

#root > div > div > div.form-container > div > div > form > div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: yellowgreen !important;
}

div.ui.grid.container > .form-container > .ui.stackable > form{
   background-color: magenta !important;
  }
```

HTML CODE

```
<div className="form-container">
          <div className="ui stackable">
            <div className="row">
              <Form
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                noValidate
                className={loading ? "loading" : ""}
              >
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <Form.Input
                  label="Username"
                  placeholder="Username.."
                  name="username"
                  type="text"
                  value={values.username}
                  error={errors.username ? true : false}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <Form.Input
                  label="Password"
                  placeholder="Password.."
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={values.password}
                  error={errors.password ? true : false}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
                <Button
                  onClick={() => Redirect("/")}
                  type="submit"
                  id="login-btn"
                  primary
                >
                  Log In
                </Button>
              </Form>
              <Button
                onClick={() => history.push("/register")}
                id="register-btn"
                primary
              >
                Register
              </Button>
              {Object.keys(errors).length > 0 && (
                <div className="ui error message">
                  <ul className="list">
                    {Object.values(errors).map((value) => (
                      <li key={value}>{value}</li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check if the css file is linked correctly or not, I pasted your code in codesandbox and it worked fine for me, the inputs had blue background. Or you can explain what are you expecting this code to do and what's happening in detail